# Counting occurrences of attributes in a sequence in XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a sequence called `$answer` with the attributes I extracted from elements from an XML file. Inside `$answer` I have the following 3 attributes: `1, 3, 3` and another sequence of attributes called `$p` with: `1, 3`

I tried to do this to get the number of occurrences by doing

```
for $x in $p
return count (index-of($x, $answer))
```

since I saw it as a solution in another posting but it gave me errors. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: What error did it give using which implementation? What exactly does your input-sequence look like (maybe just write it like you would do as input in a query so we can work with it) and what should the output be? I'm not totally aware of your problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to sort all your attributes by its values? The group by statement might give you the expected results:

```
for $a in (attribute a {'A'}, attribute b {'B'}, attribute a {'A'})
group by $v := $a
return concat(count($a), ': ', $v)
```

Note, however, that your XQuery implementation needs to support XQuery 3.0.

Comment: What I want in the end is to return how many times 1 occurs in $answer (once) and 3 occurs in $answer(2). I'm working with Xquery 1.0 so there is no group by unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the arguments you passed to index-of():

```
for $x in $p
return count(index-of($answer, $x))
```

But a simpler way is to test for equality in a predicate:

```
for $x in $p
return count($answer[. eq $x])
```

which produces the same result for the given data.